# How to Loop Through all Posts and Count Attachments using Get Media Attachments

Tags: plugins, php, wp-query, html, get-posts

I am working, on a code, where i need to loop Through all posts of a given author, and then for each post of that author, count the number of media attachments, the post has and then echo it.

I am able to loop Through posts, and it works as expected, but then i want to count the number of attachments of each post, where i fail, please help.

```
$author_posts = get_posts( array('author' => $author_id, 'numberposts' => -1, 'post_type'=> array('post','download', 'attachment' ), 'post_status'=> array('publish','privatised'), ));
```

This was the orignal loop.

Below is the code, here the words are counted as expected, comments are counted as expected too. For simplicity in prefered not to include the echo portion

```
 foreach ( $author_posts as $post ) {   
$View_Count = absint( get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'Creation_Views', true ) ); 
$Word_Count = str_word_count( strip_tags( get_post_field( 'post_content', $post->ID )));
$Image_Count = count( get_attached_media( 'image', $post->ID ) );
$Comment_Count = get_comments_number($post->ID) ;
```

Please help, the $Image_Count, always gives 0, regardless of which post i check. I have over 500 posts, and it shows 0 for all of them, while all of them atleast have 1 attachment

Answer (score 1):

If you are counting post images, try the following.  It doesn't capture a post's featured image, but it does get images in the post content.

```
$attached_images = get_children( "post_parent=$post->ID&post_type=attachment&post_mime_type=image;
$Image_Count=count($attached_images);
```

Comment: Well honestly, i wanted every attachment uploaded to a post, regardless of whether it has been inserted in content or not. This could include featured imgs, vids etc... But still i can manage with it. So thank you

Comment: I haven't tested, but, possibly, you could leave off the part of the query that is: '&post_mime_type=image' and get all attachment types.  Separately, this page:  https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_mime_type  discusses the different mime types that could be queried.

Answer (score 1):

Must be used inside the loop

```
$post_images = get_children( $post->ID );
$images_count = count( $post_images );
echo $images_count;
```